# Cannot boot after hard shutdown (modsign db list...)

Tags: boot

I can't boot to ubuntu anymore since the day I hard shutdown my pc a few days ago.

I've tried everything I could find on the internet, but i couldn't solve the problem...

Here are three images that describes the problem I have :

[image]

[image]

[image]

I have tried :

- launching in recovery mode
- running fsck from live-cd
- running boot-repair from live-cd
- activating/deaactivating secure boot

and it does not work I still have the errors...

can someone help me please ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Running fsck on the system partition `/dev/sda2` and on `/dev/sda3` where errors were also found actually solved the problem.

Comment: Please set your answer as solution.